# Accessing Tree Structure from another cpp file

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a treeModel. Which i am able to access in the following way.

```
void SumTreeProject::insertRow()
 {
    QModelIndex index = treeView->selectionModel()->currentIndex();
    QAbstractItemModel *model = treeView->model();
    TreeModel *myModel = qobject_cast<TreeModel*>(model);

    if (!model->insertRow(index.row() + 1, index.parent()))
      return;

      Container cont;
     QModelIndex child = model->index(index.row() + 1, 0, 
      index.parent());
     model->setData(child, QVariant("Container"), Qt::EditRole);
     myModel->SetContainer(child, cont);

    QModelIndex indexRoot = treeView->rootIndex();
    iterate(indexRoot, model);
   }
```

I want to access the same Model from some other Cpp file.

I tried to move in all the headers but it creates a new  model rather than me accessing the already existing model.

This is my Constructor defination.

```
 WavefrontRenderer::WavefrontRenderer(QWidget *parent)
   : QMainWindow(parent)
   {
     setupUi(this);

     Container c;
     TreeModel *model = new TreeModel("RootElement", c);
      treeView->setModel(model);
      treeView->setDragEnabled(true);
      treeView->setAcceptDrops(true);
  }
```

I tried to access the Model by making a object of the WavefrontRenderer class but then realised that it is making a new Model Structure rather than accesing the already built Model structure.

Comment: you can share the model by passing it as a reference to the `WavefrontRenderer` contractor

Comment: Simon could you please show me some reference code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new instance of the model will create a new model.

One way to share your model is to pass it to the other class

for example

```
    WavefrontRenderer::WavefrontRenderer(QWidget *parent, TreeModel * poOtherTreeModel )
         : QMainWindow(parent)
   {
     setupUi(this);

     Container c;
     //TreeModel *model = new TreeModel("RootElement", c);

      treeView->setModel(poOtherTreeModel); // TBD: for safety test for nullptr
      treeView->setDragEnabled(true);
      treeView->setAcceptDrops(true);
  }
```

Then use the tree model in the `SumTreeProject` class and pass it to the `WavefrontRenderer` constractor